# Quick Look preview via QLpreviewcontroller in Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, quicklook, representable

Hi how do you make QuickLook usable in swiftui?
You have to implement QLpreviewcontroller with Representable.  How do you do this?

I have some pdfs that are local and i wanted to use Bundle to locate them and have the pdfs shared to email and text via QLPreviewController from a swiftui button push.  Can you point me in the correct direction?